# How can I make this JButton work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am working on a code that will generate a random number when you press a button and output that number. I have wrote this code and it compiles but when I press the button nothing works. Can someone please help. Here is some of my code.

```
public class slotmachine extends JApplet {

    JButton b1 = new JButton("START");
    JPanel p;
    int Int1;

    public slotmachine() {
        init();

    }

    public void init() {

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1000, 1000);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("START");
        b1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);

        getContentPane().add(b1);
        repaint();

    }

    public void run() {
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Random random1 = new Random();
                int Int1 = random1.nextInt(11);

            }

        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("Your number is" + Int1, 30, 30);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `null` layouts.

Comment: Try removing 
  JButton b1 = new JButton("START"); from the init() method as you have already declared it inside the class. Or instead, declare the variable as it is, but inside init() initialise it. Also inside your action performed method. Don't initialise a new variable, instead assign a value to that already declare inside the class. You also need to call repaint() to update the app

Comment: I could not find a layout that includes the ability of setting the coordinates and sizes of buttons. Also Alan, I tried everything you said but it still will not work. Still, thanks for your help.

Comment: It has worked for me by simply reusing the variables you are declaring and adding the listener and assignments to the correct objects. Remove the JButton b1 = new JButton() from the init() method and move your action listener underneath b1.setBounds(). Call repaint() inside your action listener and add super.paintComponents(g) to the paint method

Comment: @Alan NEVER suggest to ANYBODY to call `super.paintComponents` from within any method other then `paintComponents`, you've just circumvented the painting process which could result in unwanted painting glicthes

Comment: thankyou Alan, this worked very well!

Comment: @goolybug although my solution worked - take note of what MadProgrammer has suggested (particularly regarding not calling paintComponents inside the paint method).

Comment: I will make sure to look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify
2. You create a local variable of `Int1` within the `ActionListener` for the button.  This has no relationship to the `Int1` of the class.
3. You never tell the UI to update
4. You break the paint chain by failing to call `super.paint` (be ready for some seriously weird and wonderful graphics glitches)
5. You've made the same mistake with `b1` as you have with `Int1`.  You create an instance level field, but shadow it with a local variable in `init`, meaning when `start` is called, `b1` is `null`, which will result in a `NullPointerxception`

Instead, add a `JLabel` to your applet, use it's `setText` method to display the random value

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Random random1 = new Random();
        int Int1 = random1.nextInt(11);
        lable.setText(Integer.toString(Int1));
    }

});
```

Also, if possible, I'd avoid using `JApplet`, they have their own set of issues which can make life more difficult then it needs to be when learning the Swing API.  Instead, try using a `JPanel` for your main container and then add it to an instance of a `JFrame`.

Also, take a look at:

- [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more information about local and class/instance context for variables
- [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)
- [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- And if your really interested in how painting works, [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

for more details

Comment: Thx for all the links and the advice. I will try to use a layout manager instead.